# set time for flags

Tags: highcharts

Helo!
I created flag for my chart:

```
type : 'flags',
    showInLegend: false,
    data : [{
        x : Date.UTC(2012, 11, 02),
        title : '!',
        text : 'bla-bla-bla'
    }]
```

How set date and time for x? Now I set only date `Date.UTC(2012, 11, 02)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the time by adding in the time values. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp) documentation on the `Date.UTC()` method.